# Solr: Subquery concept

Tags: solr

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=_query_:{! v=cars rows=10 df=content_urdu fl=score,*}&wt=json&indent=true&rows=30&sort=pr desc
```

Please someone can explain me, what the above query will do to clear my concepts? Is the text inside curly brackets is sub-query? How will it execute?

Answer (score 1):

*query* will give you the flexibility of using different query parcers instead of the ones that is by default selected by your query handler in your mentioned example select handler.
Everything inside the braces are your parameters for the Qparser and anything outside is the q parameter for the parser but should be within the quotes. In the below example  edismax and surround parser are working  together with AND in between them. So they act as a filter. Its the same as using them in fq fields but this helps  when generating dynamic queries where there can be OR instead of AND. This feature leverages solr and lucene's multiple Qparsers and can be used together with faceting to get desired results.

```
_query_:"{!edismax rows=10 df=content_urdu } source_type:\"custom\""   AND
_query_:"{!surround maxBasicQueries=10000} content:5N(tru*,(equi* OR and*))
```